# how to remove a line of file from an other line in the same file?

Tags: java

I have a text file with the following format:

String1

String1String2

String1String2String3

....

String1Strin2String3.....String(i)...String(n)

I want to remove some parts of this file to have the following format(result file):

String1

String2

String3

...

String(i)

String(n)

I tried with this fonction but my output file is always empty:

```
public static void FileFormatted(String inputFile,String outputFile)
    {
        String FileContent = readFile(inputFile,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String[] FileSentences = FileContent.split("[\n]");
        for (int i = 0; i < FileSentences.length; i++)
        {


            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
               for(int j=1;j<FileSentences.length;j++)
                  {
                   int index= FileSentences[j].indexOf("FileSentences[i]");
                   String temp=FileSentences[j].substring(index);
                   FileSentences[j]=FileSentences[j].replaceAll(temp," ");
                        builder.append(FileSentences[j]+ "\n");
                  }
               writeIntoFile(builder, outputFile, true);

        }


    }
public static void writeIntoFile(StringBuilder stringBuilder,
            String txtFilePath, boolean append) {
        File file = new File(txtFilePath);

        // if file doesn't exists, then create it
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        FileWriter fw;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), append);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(stringBuilder.toString());
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all reading the whole file in, in one go is bad practice. Imagine you have a 6gb file, that means you need 6gb of RAM to store that file when you read it in. It would be better to read the file line by line.

So the Aim of the logic would be read line by line.
When we read the first line we can get the length of it.
When we read read the second line we know the length of the first line so that means it is our starting point on the second line. This means you can use sub-string method, passing the start position and end position. 
And repeat this logic for line 3,4,...n

The benefit of this is that you don't waste memory, you are only storing the size of the line in text.

**Update**

I have written the code that I suggested earlier. It's pretty basic and there is no validation so you will need to add to it. But it covers the basics

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("test.txt");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

      int startPosition = 0;
      String line;
      ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
      while((line = br.readLine() ) != null)
      {
          items.add(line.substring(startPosition, line.length()));
          System.out.println(line.substring(startPosition, line.length()));
          startPosition = line.length();

      }

      write("test2.txt", items);
}

public static void write (String filename, ArrayList<String> items) throws IOException{

    BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
    outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

    for (String item : items) {

        outputWriter.write(item);
        outputWriter.newLine();
    }
    outputWriter.flush();  
    outputWriter.close();  
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution...it's perfect for me...really helpful

Answer (score 0):

be sure the pattern is consistent in the hole file, then Do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String wordTofind = "String";
    String st = "String1String2String3String4";
    String[] arra = st.split(wordTofind);
    for (int i = 1; i < arra.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(wordTofind + arra[i]);
        //write to a file or similar.


    }
}
```

you can use regex too, but this is acceptable...

Comment: The file I gave was an exemple, but in real strings do not have the same length

Comment: My goal is to separate my strings and do not have redundant ones.

Comment: for exemple: first line of the text file can contain the following string:AZERT

Comment: Second line can  contain:AZERTQSD

Comment: third one: AZERTQSDWXC

Comment: but in the end my file will contains : AZERT in rhe first line, QSD in the second line and WXC in the third ones